# Remote login using ssh keys vs password. Weird Error: Is a directory

Tags: linux, ssh, remote-desktop, cygwin

I am facing a weird issue, and just stuck trying to figure out.

If i login using ssh keys (passwordless authentication), i get this error every time:

```
rsanpui@cygwin ~
$ "//DNVM/E920/System920/x86/MyWorld Client Install/install/setup.exe"
-bash: //DNVM/E920/System920/x86/MyWorld Client Install/install/setup.exe: Is a directory
```

Whereas, if i login to same machine using password authentication, no such error on executing remote exe.

```
rsanpui@cygwin ~
 $ "//DNVM/E920/System920/x86/MyWorld Client Install/install/setup.exe"
```

I tried changing permission of remote .ssh/ folder to 777 but of no use.
Can anyone suggest, am badly stuck as our application should execute using passwordless authentication?

I copied ssh keys to remote machine `rsanpui@cygwin` using `ssh-copy-id`

Comment: "_I tried changing permission of remote .ssh/ folder to 777_" put it back as 700 - you'll break `ssh` passwordless authentication if you do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to access a SMB network share. The problem is that because the SSH server did not receive your password during login, it doesn't know what password to use when authenticating against that SMB fileserver. (SMB *does not* just trust the client saying "this is uid 1000" like NFS does.)

When you connect using password authentication, the sshd  preserves the username and password in memory as part of the Windows "logon session". The logon password can then be used for accessing SMB fileservers directly, or for acquiring Kerberos tickets, or for decrypting other stored credentials.

But when you connect using SSH publickey authentication, the sshd does not know your password, and Windows does not have any way to log in to SMB fileservers without it.   You need to manually connect to those using `net use '\\DNVM'` and provide the password for each connection.

Comment: Thanks, but why does it ask for username again for remote drive now? With passwrd based login it didnt ask for the same. `Enter the user name for 'DNVM'` Also the remote drive (which is a n/w share has Read Access for All). Also, this is just a network drive, not a Samba share.

Comment: The share permissions do not matter -- you can't even begin accessing files until you log in to the SMB server. (Compare with SFTP: even though some file like /etc/motd is world-readable, you still can't access it via scp/sftp unless you log in first.)

Comment: SMB is the file sharing protocol that Windows uses -- it does not mean Samba specifically. (It's the other way around, the Samba software was named after SMB.) Whether you're accessing a Windows file server, or a Linux Samba server, or a NAS/network disk, the `//servername` still means you're still doing it through SMB.

Comment: Thanks - i will investigate and keep this thread posted.

Comment: Pardon me. My theory was wrong, and you were correct. I deleted my comments as they were misleading to a visitor in this thread. Even using rundeck user and manual ssh (passwdless) it doesnt work. Only way it works is, if these commands are stored in batch file, and rundeck software installed in Linux executes these batch files in remote nodes where cygwin is installed. Rundeck, seems to have its own key based authentication. The passwords are stored in our rundeck's key storage, for every cygwin user like: "typicaluser". And every Windows m/c have this "typicaluser" whose key is stored.

Comment: When we first time setup a Windows host (having cygwin), we set a passwordless ssh between Linux rundeck machine, and the Windows host, and store the "typicaluser" password in rundeck key-storage. So, may be rundeck is somehow using a password based authentication. May be i need to understand better of how exactly rundeck key-storage based authentication works. But thanks a lot for your answer. That helps.

Comment: It sounds like rundeck's "key-storage" is completely unrelated to SSH public key auth, it is merely a place to store all sorts of sensitive data (like Vault or Bitwarden).

Comment: As per your theory, since the manual ssh doesnt work even as "rundeck" user. When i say, rundeck user it is the Linux user created by rundeck when it is installed (not rundeck software). But the rundeck software, able to use the exe it is definitely the case that rundeck is somehow passing the password from it's key storage to the Cygwin box (not a passwdless case) which i mistakenly thought earlier, and you rightly clarified the reason. So, i think this issue is now solved, that without password it is not possible.